# Excel Macro Find & Replace Duplicate Values of a Column from bottom row to top row sequence

Tags: vba, excel

I got this vba from internet:

```vb
Sub MatchCompanyName_InsertContact_EmailAddress()
    Dim hold As New Collection

    For Each celli In Columns(6).Cells
        On Error GoTo raa
        If Not celli.Value = Empty Then
            hold.Add Item:=celli.Row, key:="" & celli.Value
        End If
    Next celli

    On Error Resume Next
    raa:
    Range("J1:L1").Offset(celli.Row - 1, 0).Value = Range("J1:L1").Offset(hold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

The code find & replace sequence is from top to bottom row, I need it to be the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reverse the items in your collection.  One way to do it would be by adding a new collection and transferring in reverse order like this:

```
raa:

Dim newHold as New Collection
For Each obj in hold
    If newHold.Count > 0 Then
        newHold.Add item := obj, before := 1
    Else
        newHold.Add item := obj
    End If
Next

Range("J1:L1").Offset(celli.Row - 1, 0).Value = Range("J1:L1").Offset(newHold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try to conbine your code but get a error:

Comment: If you want more help you will have to give more info. What is the error?  Did you make sure that the last line was updated with 'newHold' and not just 'hold'?